# when to check a checkbox other checkbox same row uncheck

Tags: asp.net, html, checkbox

i have to list check

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="18" name="yes" id="yes1">
 <input type="checkbox" value="13" name="yes" id="yes2">
 <input type="checkbox" value="12" name="yes" id="yes3">
```

and other list checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" value="14" name="no" id="no2">
<input type="checkbox" value="18" name="no" id="no2">
<input type="checkbox" value="12" name="yo" id="no2">
```

but i don't know to work when i check to checkbox id yes1 , id no1 not checked

Comment: Did you mean to give your "no" `input`s the same `id`? That is invalid HTML.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox/MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox.aspx) of ASP.Net Ajax ToolKit. In the demo, it unchecks the check box next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you change your checkboxes with `name="no"` as you have repeated IDs, and that the one with `name="yo"` is a mistake, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="18" name="yes" id="yes1">
<input type="checkbox" value="13" name="yes" id="yes2">
<input type="checkbox" value="12" name="yes" id="yes3">

<input type="checkbox" value="14" name="no" id="no1">
<input type="checkbox" value="18" name="no" id="no2">
<input type="checkbox" value="12" name="yo" id="no3">
```

You can do it like this with jQuery:

```
$("input[name=yes]").click(function() {
    var current = this.id.replace("yes","");
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#no" + current).prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$("input[name=no]").click(function() {
    var current = this.id.replace("no","");
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#yes" + current).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```